# Adding Text to a File - Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I want to add text to a new file when I enter in a text box. I don't want to override what's all ready in the file but to add a new line.

The code i have is:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("File Location", tbName.Text + " " + tbNumber.Text + " " + cbGroups.Text, False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As specified in the documentation ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/27t17sxs%28v=vs.90%29.aspx ), just change the last parameter from False to True .

Comment: Cheers, however it doesnt add the text on a new line but just next to the previous text

Comment: Ive figured it out, by adding vbCrLf

Answer (score 0):

You can use VbNewLine Or VbCrlf to carriage-return.